# Retrieve variable name in Twig

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I am using Twig templating engine an I would like to create a filter

```
{{ my_variable|default_variable }}
```

that returns the name of the variable (in this case, the string "my_variable") when the variable is empty. Is this possible? How can I retrieve the name of the variable and not its value?

Comment: You want to be able to get the variable name being passed to the filter an not just the value?

Comment: The main question is. WHY? then i may be able to help u. Cause i don't think it would a good approach to show a variable name to user.

Comment: @imsiso angular uses a similar convention to process variables. I would like a way to print the variable name to be processed by angular.

Comment: @Eyal u can use `variuable_name` instead of `{{variable_name}} and you will have the variable_name printed as a text like : 'Hello world!'. But steal i think its lake of security to show your back-end variables in browser. so if u give me an example of your problem then we may be able to find a good answer.

Comment: @Eyal Maybe posting your problem as a question can help. and then u can also put the link of your question here. (you may put codes of what you have done so far so ppl can help u more)

Answer (score 5):

I dont know that it is possible, you could pass the name you want to use as an argument to the filter

```
{{ my_variable|default_variable('my_variable') }}
```

then your filter:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('default_variable', function ($value, $defaultName) {
    return (String)$value?:$defaultName;
});
```

That will return the string version of the value of your variable or if it cant then the default name.

Comment: this is just the behaviour of the "default" filter. I wanted to avoid the repetition of 'my_variable'

Comment: haha, i hadnt really thought about it but i guess it is. Yeah sorry, i dont know of a way then.

Comment: this answer is the only possibility, tho. the variable itself is given to the function and contains no information about its name within the twig template

Comment: but hey. why? i mean why u want to do show the variable name to user? tell me what is the idea behind then i may be able to suggest a better idea